# C source code, Watcom Compiler and EMU8086

Tags: c, emu8086, watcom

How can I get the Watcom compiler (the forked version 2.0 beta which runs on 64-bit hosts) to **output 8086 assembly source code** in an ASM file? Running **wcc -0 main.c** from the command prompt produces just the OBJ file.

As a side note, my main task it to convert C source code to assembly code that I can run with EMU8086 (instead of writing the actual assembly code). I am hoping the ASM file generated by Watcom would run without modification (copy-paste) in EMU8086.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to get the Watcom compiler to generate an ASM file directly, but you should be able to use the Watcom disassembler (`wdis`) to generate an assembly listing from the object file produced by the compiler.  In this case you would run something like `wdis -l main` to read `main.obj` and produce a file named `main.lst` that contains an assembly language listing.

If you recompile main.c with a `-d1` or `-d2` option to place extra debugging data into the main.obj file then you can use the disassembler's `-s` option to have the assembly language listing  interpersed with comments showing the original C source from `main.c`.

To get the disassembler to omit descriptive comments and just give a plain disassembly that should be acceptable as a source file for the Watcom assembler, give the `-a` option to the disassembler.  This option will also causes the disassembler's output to be written into `main.asm` rather than `main.lst`.  Sorry, I have no idea whether this output will be directly consumable by EMU8086.

This is all discussed in the Open Watcom *C/C++ User Guide* and *C/C++ Tools User Guide* linked from http://www.openwatcom.com/doc.php

Comment: Thanks for your help! I followed your instructions to the letter (or rather I think I did) but as you predicted, the result wasn't directly consumable by EMU8086.